# ¿Cómo usar separadores diferentes en sed?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

Hacer una sustitución en `sed` es sencillo con la sintaxis `sed 's/busco/reemplazo/g' fichero`:

```
$ cat fichero 
hola/que/tal
yo/muy/bien
```

Por ejemplo, ahora reemplazamos todas las "a" por "XXX":

```
$ sed 's/a/XXX/g' fichero 
holXXX/que/tXXXl
yo/muy/bien
```

Sin embargo, si quiero reemplazar texto que contiene barras "hola/que" obtengo el siguiente error:

```
$ sed 's/hola/que/XXX/g' fichero 
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown option to `s'
```

De la misma forma, si quiero imprimir líneas que contienen unos caracteres determinados uso `sed -n '/patrón/p' fichero`:

```
$ sed -n '/hola/p' fichero 
hola/que/tal
```

Pero tengo el mismo error si ese patrón contiene barras, como "hola/que":

```
$ sed -n '/hola/que/p' fichero 
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: extra characters after command
```

¿Cómo puedo corregir este error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

## Escapa las barras

Si sabes a ciencia cierta el contenido de lo que buscas y puedes actuar sobre él, escapa la barra para que `sed` no lo confunda con un separador. Es decir, en lugar de decir `/`, di `\/`:

```
$ sed 's/hola\/que/XXX/g' fichero 
XXX/tal
yo/muy/bien
```

Para imprimir líneas que contienen "hola/que", lo mismo:

```
$ sed -n '/hola\/que/p' fichero 
hola/que/tal
```

## Usa otro separador

Cualquier carácter puede servidor de separador, por ejemplo "#":

```
$ sed 's#e#XXX#g' fichero 
hola/quXXX/tal
yo/muy/biXXXn

$ sed 's#hola/que#XXX#g' fichero 
XXX/tal
yo/muy/bien
```

Para imprimir líneas que contienen "hola/que", necesitamos utilizar el patrón `\cBREc` tal y como documenta POSIX en [Regular expressions in sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html#tag_04_126_13_02) (en inglés):

```
$ sed -n '\#hola/que#p' fichero
hola/que/tal
```

Obviamente, puedes combinar ambos comandos y sustituir las "/" por espacios en las líneas que contengan "hola/que":

```
$ sed '\#hola/que#s#/# #g' fichero
hola que tal
yo/muy/bien
```

#### ¿Y qué separadores puedo utilizar?

Tal y como se comenta en [What delimiters can you use in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33914546/1983854), cualquiera que no sea una barra invertida (`\`) o un salto de línea.

<sub>Sí, incluso un espacio, pero coincidirás conmigo en que la solución `sed '\ hola/que s / \  g' fichero` es cuanto menos fea.</sub>