# Cómo reeplazar cadenas en archivos .h

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Tengo una serie de scripts que hacen referencia a numpy y a la libreria Python.h. He notado que otras librerias de numpy vuelven a hacer referencia a Python.h ; este esta en /usr/include/numpy/, pero cuando compilo gcc muestra:

```
fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

luego cambio la línea de tal script por

```
#include </usr/include/numpy/Python.h>
```

a lo cual gcc avanza pero en otra libreria de numpy; obtenemos el mismo error de Python.h. Por lo que quiero cambiar todas las librerias del SO en vez de uno a uno el string de `<Python.h>` a `</usr/include/numpy/Python.h>` y para eso tengo pensado el siguiente codigo

```
#!/bin/bash

reemplaza="s/ #include <Python.h> / #include </usr/include/numpy/Python.h> /g"
find / -type f -name '*h' -exec sed -i "$reemplaza" {} +
```

pero me sale

```
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida `para `s'
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'
```

creo que es cuestión de caracteres de escape pero ¿cómo se haría?

Gracias por la ayuda amigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tema aquí es que estás reemplazando una cadena diciendo básicamente:

```
reemplaza="s/ #include <Python.h> / #include </usr/include/numpy/Python.h> /g"

sed "s/$busca/$reemplaza/g"
```

Y `$reemplaza` contiene una barra. Por tanto, lo acabas teniendo es algo así como:

```
sed "s/$busca/algo/con/barras/g"
```

Y son demasiadas barras para `sed`, de ahí que te diga:

> sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 32: opción desconocida para `s'

Pues está intentando hacer una acción del tipo "con" o "barras", que es totalmente desconocida para `sed`.

La solución consiste en utilizar otro separador en `sed` como por ejemplo `|` y decir algo así como:

```
sed "s|$busca|$reemplaza|g"
```

Puedes leer más al respecto en [¿Cómo usar separadores diferentes en sed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/57445/83)