# ¿Como funciona este comando Sed?

Tags: bash, unix, búsquedas, sed

Quería saber como es que funciona este comando letra por letra, que no lo entiendo.

```
find <directorio> -type d | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
```

La parte de `find <directorio> -type d` la entiendo bien, que sería buscar todos los subdirectorios a partir de un directorio. Lo que no entiendo como funciona es `sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'`.

Comment: te recomiendo leer sobre expresiones regulares: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este comando es una implementación manual de lo que hace el comando `tree`, tal y como expliqué en [Tree functionality using sed and find command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23953129/1983854).

---

Cuando tienes `sed -e 's/bla/ble/g;s/x/y/g'` quiere decir que se están poniendo dos comando Sed a la vez: `sed 's/bla/ble/g'` y `sed 's/x/y/g'`, de manera que lo resultante del primero se procesa en el segundo. Por tanto, empecemos separándolos.

```
sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
```

es

```
sed 's;[^/]*/;|____;g'
```

y a su resultado aplicarle:

```
sed 's;____|; |;g'
```

---

Vayamos uno a uno: **`sed 's;[^/]*/;|____;g'`**

La expresión básica de Sed es `sed 's/busca/reemplazo/X'` y lo que hace es buscar "busca" y reemplazarlo con "reemplazo" utilizando los flags descritos en X. Si este flag es `g`, quiere decir que lo haga tantas veces como pueda. Por tanto, `sed 's/busca/reemplazo/g'` reemplazará todos los "busca" con "reemplazo":

```
$ echo "hola hola" | sed 's/hola/adios/'
adios hola
$ echo "hola hola" | sed 's/hola/adios/g'
adios adios
```

Además, y como expliqué en [¿Cómo usar separadores diferentes en sed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/57445/83), Sed permite usar otros separadores en lugar de `/`, usando básicamente cualquier carácter. Esto es de ayuda para los casos, como este, en el que buscas algo como "/" y usar ese mismo carácter como separador obliga a escaparlo. Por tanto, estos son equivalentes:

```
sed 's/busca/reemplazo/g'
sed 's;busca;reemplazo;g'
```

Así, `sed 's;[^/]*/;|____;g'` lo que hace es:

- busca `[^/]*/`. Esto quiere decir cualquier carácter menos "/" y seguido de "/".
- lo sustituye por `|____`.

Por tanto, está reemplazando todos los "hola/" por "|____", así:

```
    $ echo "hola/que/tal" | sed 's;[^/]*/;|____;g'
    |____|____tal
```

Vayamos a por el otro: **`sed 's;____|; |;g'`**

De forma equivalente, esto busca todos los "____|" y los sustituye por " |".

---

Ejemplo:

```
$ mkdir hola{1..3}
$ mkdir hola{1..3}/adios{1..3}
```

Con el comando `tree` vemos:

```
$ tree
.
├── hola1
│   ├── adios1
│   ├── adios2
│   └── adios3
├── hola2
│   ├── adios1
│   ├── adios2
│   └── adios3
└── hola3
    ├── adios1
    ├── adios2
    └── adios3

12 directories, 0 files
```

Con este comando "manual", obtenemos:

```
$ find . -type d | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
.
|____hola1
| |____adios1
| |____adios3
| |____adios2
|____hola2
| |____adios1
| |____adios3
| |____adios2
|____hola3
| |____adios1
| |____adios3
```

Answer (score 2):

[Sed](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/used.htm) es un editor de `stream` no interactivo. Toma una entrada de texto, ya sea de `stdin` o de un archivo, realiza ciertas operaciones en líneas especificadas de la entrada, una línea a la vez, luego emite el resultado a `stdout` o a un archivo.

La opción:

```
**-e** script, **--expression**=script
```

toma el script 'script' para ser ejecutado.

**Ejemplo** (tomado de [aquí](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options)):

Todas estas operaciones son equivalentes. Se realizan dos operaciones: una elimina cualquier linea que coincida con la expresión regular `/ ^ foo /`, y la otra reemplaza todas las ocurrencias de la cadena 'hola' con 'mundo':

```
sed '/^foo/d ; s/hello/world/' input.txt > output.txt

sed -e '/^foo/d' -e 's/hello/world/' input.txt > output.txt

echo '/^foo/d' > script.sed
echo 's/hello/world/' >> script.sed
sed -f script.sed input.txt > output.txt

echo 's/hello/world/' > script2.sed
sed -e '/^foo/d' -f script2.sed input.txt > output.txt
```

Aquí tenés la [documentación](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) completa.

Comment: De todos modos, no veo que estés explicando en ningún caso qué hace la expresión de la pregunta.