# Usar sed con variables de entorno

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Estoy intentando usar el comando `sed` con variables de entorno en vez de literales, pero me devuelve:

> unterminated `s' command

En caso de poner un literal, sí que funciona, pero si pongo una variable, no.
He probado varias soluciones encontradas por aquí, pero ninguna me sirve:

```
sed "s/<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>/<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>$stringEncoded/" 20200609.xml
```

También:

```
sed 's/<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>/<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>'"$stringEncoded"'/' 20200609.xml
```

También:

```
sed -i "s/^\( *<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>\)\([^>]*\)</\1$ficheroEncoded</" 20200609.xml
```

Ejemplo de 20200609.xml:

```
<Envio>
 <DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO></DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>
</Envio>
```

Ejemplo de variable $stringEncoded:

```
6ZSAxOTEvSW5mbyA2IDAgUi9Sb290IDE3OSAwIFIKPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjQy NDUyCiUlRU9GCg==
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Dicho esto, ¿podrías decirnos qué contiene `$stringEncoded`? Recuerda que no puede contener delimitadores o, en caso contrario, estarás rompiendo la regla de sustitución.

Comment: Mientras editas tu pregunta con más información, voto el cierre por no poder reproducirse el problema con los datos facilitados.

Comment: He añadido nueva informacion en el enunciado

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Sed utilizas? Yo, igual que @OscarGarcia, no puedo reproducir el problema

Comment: Voy a consultarlo. Edit: no se muy bien como saber que version de sed estoy usando. como podria saberlo ?

Comment: Nos vendría bien conocer el sistema operativo y la versión. En caso de instalar versiones que no estén en los repositorios de ese sistema operativo, nos vendría bien la versión de bash y sed.

Comment: A parte de darle mi `+1` a @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', te he redactado una respuesta con otra alternativa manteniendo el uso de `sed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meter una variable Bash en un contexto de Sed es peligroso: al integrarse directamente en el código, puede romper la sintaxis. Puedes usar otros delimitadores para mitigar el problema, como se describe en [¿Cómo usar separadores diferentes en sed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/57445/83), pero si la variable puede tener cualquier carácter es apenas una huida adelante.

Por ello, resulta más *limpio* diferenciar variables de sintaxis usando por ejemplo Awk:

```
awk -v valor="$var" '{$0=gensub(/(<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>)/,"\\1" valor, 1)}1' fichero
```

Incluso puedes ir más allá y también puedes pasar el texto de "<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>":

```
awk -v patron="<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>" -v valor="$var" '{$0=gensub("(" patron ")","\\1" valor, 1)}1' fichero
```

La clave del comando `{$0=gensub(/(<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>)/,"\\1" valor, 1)}1` es:

- `{}1` haz acciones y cuando termines evalúa 1, que hace que se imprima la línea actual, ya modificada.
- `$0=gensub(/(<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>)/,"\\1" valor, 1)` define la línea completa (`$0`) como el resultado de [`gensub( , , )`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).
- `gensub(/(<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>)/,"\\1" valor, 1)` dice que busque las ocurrencias de "<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>" y las modifique por `\1` seguido de la variable `valor`, donde `\1` es el texto cogido en el primer bloque (es decir, evitamos volver a escribir "<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>" básicamente. Con el `1` final le decimos que lo haga una vez; si usáramos "g" haría la modificación tantas veces como pudiera.

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentar entenderlo y lo pruebo!

Comment: Vaya tio, muchas gracias. Funciona perfecto ... parece magia. Estudiaré mas que hace el awk y el gensub por que me cuesta entenderlo.
Una ultima duda, el documento no se actualiza. debo usar algo tipo " > fichero" para que se actualize ?

Comment: Qué bien que te funcionara, @QuimSerra. Awk hace bastante magia y es muy práctico para cosas del día a día. El comando que puse aquí es algo complejo, por lo que te recomiendo empezar con cosas más sencillas para que no te asustes :) Una lectura que siempre recomiendo es [Idiomatic Awk](https://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/). Y sí, para actualizar usa `>`, por ejemplo `awk '...' fichero > nuevo && mv nuevo fichero`. Al fin y al cabo, es lo que hace `sed -i` internamente.

Answer (score 2):

Con el XML compartido y las instrucciones `sed` proporcionadas no he sido capaz de reproducir el problema que sufres (*unterminated `s' command*).

Como puedes ver, todos funcionan correctamente menos el último (que no hace nada porque no hay nada que coincida con ese patrón):

```
$ stringEncoded="6ZSAxOTEvSW5mbyA2IDAgUi9Sb290IDE3OSAwIFIKPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjQyNDUyCiUlRU9GCg="

$ sed "s/<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>/<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>$stringEncoded/" 20200609.xml
<Envio>
 <DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>6ZSAxOTEvSW5mbyA2IDAgUi9Sb290IDE3OSAwIFIKPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjQyNDUyCiUlRU9GCg=</DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>
</Envio>

$ sed 's/<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>/<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>'"$stringEncoded"'/' 20200609.xml
<Envio>
```

<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>6ZSAxOTEvSW5mbyA2IDAgUi9Sb290IDE3OSAwIFIKPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjQyNDUyCiUlRU9GCg=</DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>

Puedes usar `sed` para hacer el trabajo que deseas, pero **debes entender el peligro que supone que la variable contenga el carácter separador**. En el caso de que sea una cadena codificada en **base64** (como parece ser el contenido que vas a reemplazar) entonces no hay peligro alguno.

En ese caso, podrías usar la siguiente instrucción `sed`:

```
$ stringEncoded="Texto # con # delimitadores"
$ sed -r "s#(<DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>)(</DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>)#\1${stringEncoded//#/\\#}\2#" 20200609.xml
<Envio>
 <DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>Texto # con # delimitadores</DOCUMENTO_ASOCIADO>
</Envio>
```

He hecho tres cambios a tus patrones:

- He usado el modificador `-r` para poder usar con comodidad paréntesis con captura en la expresión regular.
- He usado como delimitador el carácter `#` para evitar que se reconozca el carácter `/` del cierre de etiqueta XML como final del patrón.
- He sustituido todos los delimitadores `#` dentro de la variable por `\#` mediante `${stringEncoded//#/\\#}`. De esa forma se interpretará `\#` como un carácter `#` al sustituirlo, no como delimitador de la sustitución:

  - `//#` significa *busca todos los caracteres `#`*.
  - `/\\#` significa *sustitúyelos por `\#`*.

Comment: he puesto nueva info en el enunciado :)

Comment: He editado la respuesta con otra alternativa manteniendo el uso de `sed`.

Comment: Buena respuesta, bien construida. Viendo las dos soluciones que hemos sugerido, parece que todos vamos estando de acuerdo que es mejor usar herramientas específicas para modificar XML, pues hacerlo con Sed, Awk y similares es un dolor de cabeza importante.

Comment: +1. El problema que no puedo instalar librerías ni actualizarlar el batch ( no depende de mi :S )