# ¿Cómo quito dos barras iniciales de un texto con sed?

Tags: linux, regex, bash, sed

Hola gente estoy intentando cambiar este texto:

```
//$('#myamerico22').modal('show');
```

a este

```
$('#myamerico22').modal('show');
```

mediante sed en Linux

intento con este comando pero no me funciona!!

Intente hacerlo con expresiones regulares pero no funciona.

Donde esta el error ??

Ayuda por favor

```
sed -i "s/\/\/\$\(\'#myamerico22\'\)\.modal\(\'show\'\)\;/\$\(\'#myamerico22\'\)\.modal\(\'show\'\)\;/g" mis-scripts.js
```

Intente con comillas simples y dobles.

Comment: Try **sed -Ei '' 's/\/\/(\$\(.#myamerico22.\)\.modal\(.show.\);)/\1/g' mis-scripts.js**. I'm assuming you only need to remove trailing slashes...

Comment: Hi, I tried it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tema es que puedes usar otro separador, tal y como se ve en [¿Cómo usar separadores diferentes en sed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/57445/83). En base a ello, puedes usar por ejemplo la `~` y escribir:

```
sed "s~//\$('#myamerico22').modal('show');~//\$('#myamerico22').modal('show');~"
```

Fíjate que lo que tienes que escapar es la `$`, pues de lo contrario tiene un significado especial.

Comment: Me funcionó perfectamente.. Ahora bien cambiando los separadores puedo usar caracteres como /*() ? Y solo tengo que escapar el $. ?

Comment: Sí, la cuestión es utilizar un separador que no esté en el texto que modificas. Ahora bien, `$` dentro de comillas dobles se interpreta como variable de Bash, por lo que hay que escaparlo.

Comment: y xq no funcionaba si estaba escapando esos caracteres con barra invertida ?.. Si con gusto acepto la respuesta.

Comment: @AndersonSosa porque el paréntesis no tenías que escaparlo: `"s/\/\/\$('#myamerico22\')\.modal(\'show\')\;/X/"` sí funcionaría.

Comment: Ohh me queda claro.! Sos el/la mejor!

Answer (score 0):

Sé que lo pediste con `sed` pero puedes intentar con `perl`:

```
$ perl -lpe 's/(^\s*)(\/\/)(.*)/$1$3/'
```

Donde la expresión regular busca tres grupos (lo encerrado entre paréntesis):

1. Lo que vaya entre el inicio de línea y multiples (cero o más) espacios
2. El indicador de comentario
3. El resto siguiente

Después será imprimido cada match. En este caso pusimos `$1$3` para que el segundo (el indicador de comentario) sea eliminado:

```
$ perl -lpe 's/(^\s*)(\/\/)(.*)/$1$3/' <<< '//$("#myamerico22").modal("show");'
$("#myamerico22").modal("show");
```

**Nota que cambié el tipo de comillas para evitar escapar cualquier otro caracter**

Puedes ir por la misma aproximación a usando `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's@(^[[:space:]]*)(//)(.*)@\1\3@' <<< '//$("#myamerico22").modal("show");
$("#myamerico22").modal("show");
```

Quizás esto no responde a tu pregunta y hace más cosas, debido a que sólo le importa que la línea esté comentada con `//`.