# sed: reemplazar en una variable que contenga la barra inclinada / por \/

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Estoy intentando, usando `sed`, reemplazar una **variable string** que contiene la barra `/` , sustituirla por `\/`.

La cosa es que el mismo carácter es el separador `/` del comando `sed`, por lo que es realmente confuso para mí.

Realmente hay 2 aspectos en esta pregunta, el segundo es que quiero **cambiar una variable, no un archivo**. Pero esto es secundario, si no es posible, lo guardaré en un archivo y luego lo editaré con `sed`.

Según este enlace => https://www.sysadmit.com/2015/07/linux-reemplazar-texto-en-archivos-con-sed.html , estoy utilizando el comando:

```
// SINTAXIS => sed -i 's/OLD_TEXT/NEW_TEXT/g' "file.txt"    

// PRUEBA OK => Sustituir ocurrencias [pom => POM] en my_file.txt
// sed -i 's/pom/POM/g' "my_file.txt" 

// PRUEBA NOK => Sustituir ocurrencias [/ => \/] en my_variable  
sed  's/X/\X/g' $my_variable
```

Este es el objetivo principal. Pongo los parámetros entre las 3 `/`.  Quito `-i` ya que esto es para editar un archivo.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Comprendo, gracias, ni me fijé. Ya está traducido.
Un saludo.

Comment: Tienes dos soluciones. Una es escapar el contenido de la variable y la otra es usar un separador diferente. ¿Cuál prefieres?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo usar separadores diferentes en sed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57445/c%c3%b3mo-usar-separadores-diferentes-en-sed)

Comment: Para que los caracteres en tu pregunta no sean escapados debes delimitar el texto usando comillas invertidas. De ese modo se interpreta como código y no se sustituye ningún carácter.

Answer (score 2):

**Nota:** Esta pregunta es un duplicado de esta otra: [¿Cómo usar separadores diferentes en sed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57445/c%c3%b3mo-usar-separadores-diferentes-en-sed)

---

**Anterior respuesta:**

Prueba con esta expresion regular y con estos otros delimitadores:

```
my_variable="hola / don pepito / hola / don josé //"

echo $my_variable | sed "s#\/#\\\/#g"
```

Eso produce esta salida:

```
hola \/ don pepito \/ hola \/ don josé \/\/
```

**Explicación**

1. Hemos cambiado los delimitadores usuales `/` por este otro `#`
2. Hemos escapado los caracteres especiales `/` y `\` con el caracter de escape `\`, quedando así la expresión regular:

```
s#\/#\\\/#g
```

Y por último, hemos realizado un `echo`de la variable que contiene la cadena pasándosela por un pipe (tuberia) al comando `sed` siguiente:

```
echo $my_variable | sed "s#\/#\\\/#g"
```

Creo que era lo que buscabas hacer.

Comment: puedes usar `sed '...' <<< "$variable"` también

Comment: Disculpa el retraso en responder. Te agradezco mucho la respuesta, me sirvió el comando ===> echo $my_variable | sed "s#\/#\\\/#g"

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres usar `sed` y `bash` puedes hacer uso de *here strings*:

```
sed 's|/|\\/|g' <<<"$my_variable"
sed 's/\//\\\//g' <<<"$my_variable"
```

En ambos casos hay que escapar la contrabarra para que no se interprete como carácter de escape y solo en el segundo caso hay que escapar las barras para que no se interpreten como delimitadores.

El [modificador `g` (*global*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) sirve para reemplazar todas las coincidencias, no solo la primera.

Si no, puedes usar un `echo` previo para conseguir lo mismo:

```
echo "$my_variable" | sed 's|/|\\/|g'
echo "$my_variable" | sed 's/\//\\\//g'
```

Por último, puedes hacer el trabajo sin necesidad de usar `sed` mediante las sustituciones de patrones:

```
echo "${my_variable//\//\\/}"
```

Según el manual:

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> **Pattern substitution.** If pattern begins with /, all matches of pattern are replaced with string.  Normally only the first match is replaced.

En castellano:

> `${parámetro/patrón/cadena}`
>
> **Patrón de sustitución.** Si el patrón comienza por `/`, todas las coincidencias del patrón son reemplazadas por la cadena. Normalmente solo la primera coincidencia es reemplazada.

Es decir, en mi ejemplo he usado dos barras para indicar que haga todas las sustituciones, haciendo uso de la construcción `${parámetro//patrón/cadena}`, donde patrón es `\/` (escapo el separador) y la cadena a sustituir es `\\/` (escapo solo la contrabarra para que no la interprete como carácter de escape, la barra normal no es necesario porque se espera fin de llaves).

Comment: Hola, disculpa el retraso en responder. He votado la respuesta de masterguru, pero también he aprendido de la tuya. No había oido nunca lo de here strings.
Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo, Oscar!

Comment: Gracias, siempre me alegra ser de ayuda. Quería diferenciarme de la otra respuesta de tres maneras diferentes: 1) mostrando cómo hacer lo mismo sin cambiar el separador, 2) mostrando el uso de *here strings*, 3) mostrando cómo hacer el trabajo sin herramientas externas como `sed`.